# Can we create a grouped bar chart using OOTB features of salesforce?

Tags: dashboard

I want to create a goruped chart for number of cases grouped depending on their turn around time (within(grren color),avg(orange color),beyond average(blue color)) versus the contacts with group-platinum,gold,silver[image]

Comment: this should be doable.  You can direct help on Salesforce Success Forum; here - you'll need to provide a bit more information about your objects and fields - and show what you've tried with results